# Unable to get an array of required size from random_seed subroutine

Tags: random, fortran, command-line-arguments, random-seed

Based on what I understood from the description of RANDOM_SEED Subroutine here,
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html

I tried to get an array of size *n* by taking *n* as an input argument. However, I always get array of a fixed size (n = 33) no matter what I input in the argument of the executable. What am I doing wrong?

```
program test_random_seed
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: seed(:)
  integer :: n
 Character(len=2) :: inputnum

 call GETARG(1, inputnum)
 read (inputnum, *) n

  call random_seed(size = n)
  allocate(seed(n))
  call random_seed(get=seed)
  write (*, *) seed
  deallocate(seed)
end program test_random_seed
```

Outputs:

```
./test_random_seed.out 6
   270997589  -288181887  1948167863  -899467666   856399949  -616956193  -393084398  -169799794 -2106914961 -1327699024  -611308309  -956136276 -1047101846  1405583576 -2030082380  1642309723  -964872898  -478908624   486119102  1947066547  -722265400  -268681072   366932413  -791652926  1961977905  -349345081   465186042   808162632  -129440729  -683435376  1183730510   264749721           0
```

```
./tes_trandom_seed.out 4
   911554020  -223715509  -703604837 -1861804415  1952830407 -1126364511 -1115643071 -1251893035  1013863844  1767892501  1999133695 -1456139371 -1813327006  1135316397 -2034112324 -1863710425   749654783  1021195219  1479800515   882047462 -1297200646  1932542969 -1428989180  1078641551  -431962594 -1403398736   620407660   472937510  1677653929  1187629179  -357974360   953325445           0
```

Comment: Parameter `SIZE` is INTENT(OUT). This is the Fortran library telling you what size it needs the seed array to have. Depends on the nature of the random number generator. You might want to print variable n just before the `allocate` call.

Comment: @jpmarinier I did that, and it yields n=33 always

Comment: @ferro11001 As jpmarinier says the size is `Intent(Out)`. You can't set the size. The library has already decided on a value (33 in this case), this is your way of asking what the value is, *not* a way of changing it. Within Fortran there is no way of changing it.

Comment: @Ian Bush, then how do I set an upper-bound to the size of my random array? maybe just extract first m out of n values from the array if I desire m<n?

Comment: @ferro11001 So in your Fortran installation, it takes 33 32 bits words to store the current state of the random number generator.

Comment: Are you trying to use `random_seed` to generate your random numbers? If so you are using the wrong routine - you want the subroutine `random_number`. The routine you are using merely initialises the random sequence, it doesn't give you any random numbers

Comment: I am trying to do just that - initialize a random sequence. I realize I should've said random-seed array in the earlier comment. I am using a Mersenne Twister subroutine to initialize *m* random configurations simultaneously, for which I need random seeds. I was using sequential numbers as seeds so far and wanted to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your last comment is that you are trying to initialize `n` independent pseudorandom sequences and give them individual seeds. That is not possible in standard Fortran using `random_seed()`. The array that `random_seed()` uses is *a single seed* for a single sequence. The size of the array is fixed to specify the exact number of bits necessary for that single seed.

When using coarrays, it is possible to use `random_init()` to request an independent sequence for each image.

You claim you are using the Mersenne twister. The Fortran standard does not specify the algorithm used for the intrinsic pseudorandom generator. Older versions of gfortran did IIRC use this algorithm, but newer versions are using a different one.

If you are using some third-party Mersenne twister library, then you have to use the seeding subroutines supplied by that library. Using `random_seed()` only effects the intrinsic pseudorandom generator.

Please note that there is also no mechanism ta call `random_number()` for independent sequences. What happens, when you call `random_number()` from multiple threads is processor-dependent and you should consult the compiler manual.